# Where does the other end of the secondary in a solid state tesla coil connect?

Tags: tesla-coil

Yes, i know it's a very elementary question, it's my first time build. All circuits shows that the not- sparking end of a sstc is connected to ground,  but exactly where? do they mean the LITERALL ground or the ground on the wall outlet or just leave it unconnected?
It's based on Steve Wards mini SSTC

Comment: If you are confused by this, then STOP playing as you may well hurt yourself.

Answer (score 3):

It's a source of confusion, even for (some) builders of Tesla coils. Or at least, where best to connect it is.

The current that flows from the high voltage terminal of a TC has to return somehow to the bottom terminal. As the frequency is several hundred kHz, and the impedance is very high, just the few pFs of capacitance between the top terminal and 'ground' is adequate.

What's 'ground'. If you are running in the middle of a field, it's obviously the earth beneath your feet. If you are running in an apartment on the 14th floor, it's actually the mains wiring and any metallic pipes in the walls, the floor, the ceiling. Some of these may be connected together, some may be relatively isolated. This is where the spark currents may introduce voltages between (say) the line conductors and the earth conductors in your building's wiring, and upset your, and your neighbours' electronic equipment.

What people running indoors will often do is to use a 'counterpoise', a large sheet of alli foil or chicken netting laid out on the floor beneath the coil. This becomes the ground, at least the major ground at RF. Connect the secondary bottom, the mains wiring ground, and any safety gap and filter returns here.

When running indoors, it's also a really good idea to connect some X2 rated capacitors between line conductors and mains earth at the coil supply, to short these together at RF. This reduces the amount of voltage that the TC currents will induce in the wiring.

Comment: Tesla himself was most interested in using his contraption to deliver power *to (through) the earth*, so he ensured extensive ground connection. His difficulty was with the weak connection at the "hot" end, which dissipated power away in impressive displays. Perhaps he'd be more successful if a more secure connection to the ionosphere could be achieved?

Comment: @glen_geek Tesla during interviews mentioned that he'd achieved this ionospheric connection (but since the word "ionosphere" didn't exist, he described it in different terms.)  He didn't need the balloon-lofted wires anymore. Also, he specifically stated that UV spotlights didn't work over longer than 100ft. "You will then see something like an aurora borealis across the sky, and the energy will go to the distant place." - Tesla, 1916

Answer (score 0):

> It's based on Steve Wards mini SSTC

The circuit produced by Steve Ward is fairly explicit: -

[image]

I've added red boxes around the two symbols for mains ground used: -

- For incoming mains ground i.e. the ground on your AC home wiring and
- The ground at the bottom of the secondary coil (the same electrical point).

> do they mean the LITERALL ground or the ground on the wall outlet or
>   just leave it unconnected?

The wall outlet ground and this, for most sane and sensible electrical installations should be rodded through to proper [terra-firma](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Solid_earth) ground.

Answer (score 0):

Beware:  for coil harmonics up in the rf (well above 500KHz) you can easily hit a cable-resonance in the power cable ground.  Suddenly you'll start getting stung when touching your microwave or fridge.  Also, you'll be broadcasting for miles, since your "ground" wire becomes an antenna.

And excellent ground for a small TC is a metal table top under the coil system.

So, connect to a metal (magnetic) workbench surface with a screw driven in the sheet metal.  Or, just cover a very large piece of cardboard with foil (4ft if you can find some,) stick it under your coil, and for a ground-wire then strip a few inches of stranded wire, splay it out and tape it to the foil.  Or, try a 3ft section of steel-mesh "hardware cloth."  And then, also run a separate ground wire to the screw of an electric outlet.

A Tesla Coil is a high-voltage animal, hence it's actually a capacitor.   It's connected to a tiny plate (the hv terminal) adjacent to an enormous plate (the ground.)   To confine the strong EM fields so they don't spew all over your apartment building, just connect the base of your TC secondary to a very large conductor-plate that's right under the coil.

Note that whenever you're in the e-field of a Tesla Coil, you'll get shocks/burns if you then brush your fingertips against grounded metal.   So, if you're using large sheets of foil as a nearby ground, perhaps you'll want to cover them with a pad, or turn your cardboard with brown-side-up.  Or even attach the foil or mesh sheets to the underside of your workbench.